# Write mock test for entity field

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I am trying to write mock test for following if statement:

```
if (Application.GetGroup("Hospital").GetEntity(i).GetField("hosp_id").GetInternalValue() == "Y")
{
    //some code.
}
```

I tried following:

```
var mockHosp = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IEntity>();
hospGrp.Stub(x => x.GetEntity(0)).Return(mockHosp);

var hosp_id = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IField>();
hospGrp.Stub(x => mockHosp.GetField("hosp_id")).Return(hosp_id);            
hosp_id.Stub(x => x.Value).Return("Y");
```

I keep getting `InvalidOperationException` on this line:

```
hospGrp.Stub(x => mockHosp.GetField("hosp_id")).Return(hosp_id);
```

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Given that GetField method seems to belong to the IEntity interface, you should stub it under that like

```cs
mockHosp.Stub(x => x.GetField("hosp_id")).Return(hosp_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Putting out a solution here may be it will help someone out:

```
var mockHosp = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IEntity>();
hospGrp.Stub(x => x.GetEntity(0)).Return(mockHosp);
mockHosp.Stub(x => x.Id).Return("1");

var hosp_id = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IField>();
hospGrp.Stub(x => x.GetField("hosp_id")).Return(hosp_id);
hosp_id.Stub(x => x.Value).Return("Y");
```